# Error saying I need to use f:metadata even though I do

Tags: jsf, metadata, jsf-2.2

After update from JSF 2.1 to 2.2, I start getting the following error message:

`The metadata component needs to be nested within a f:metadata tag. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <f:metadata>`

It's a bit weird as the code looks like this:

```
....
 <ui:composition template="./resources/templates/template_base.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="contentBody">

            <h:outputStylesheet library="css/table" name="tableContent.css" />
            <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="pagination.js" target="head" />

            <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />

            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="topicId" value="#{topicBean.topic.id}" />
                <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{topicBean.init(true)}" />
            </f:metadata>

        </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
....
```

If the metadata component the error message refers to is either `f:viewParam` or `f:event`, then I do have it/them enclosed by `f:metadata`.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? The error does not show if I set `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Production`, but I would like to keep it in `Development` until I'm finished.

Edit1 - Versions:

- `Netbeans`: 7.3.1 (Build 201306052037)
- `Java`: 1.7.0_25; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.25-b01
- `Runtime`: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_25-b16
- `Java EE`: Java EE 7 Web
- `JSF implementation`: Mojarra 2.2.0
- `Glassfish`: 4.0 build 89

Comment: Which JSF 2.2 impl/version?

Comment: I've added more info about versions in the end of the post

Comment: I don't have Mojarra 2.2.0 at hands right now, but I can't reproduce in Mojarra 2.2.1. What if you put `<f:metadata>` in its own `<ui:define>` which ends up in an `<ui:insert>` as immediate child of `<f:view>`, exactly as recommended in tag documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html Mojarra is more lenient in this, but MyFaces is known to fail like that when not done as per the recommendation.

Comment: I will try that. I'm also using PrimeFaces if that can affect anything. I didn't mention that as thought that it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: It shouldn't :) At least not in this specific case.

Comment: Good. One less thing to worry about :)

Comment: Finally got around testing a separate `ui:define` for the metadata. It made no difference though :/

Comment: Well, maybe your runtime classpath is polluted with multiple JSF versions which conflicted with each other. Doublecheck and cleanup.

Comment: I tried to get this information through using `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader` and then `getURLs()`. When printing it only shows `glassfish.jar` and `flashlight-agent.jar`, so I'm not sure how to check this. Can you point me in the right direction to find the complete classpath?

Comment: I think it's a bug. I remember seeing a bug report about this when I was helping someone. I'll see if I can find the link to be sure.

Comment: Yep, I reread your question. I remember reading something about this but only when you set your project as DEVELOPMENT.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I set `PROJECT_STAGE` to production, the error message disappeared. Problem is that I really wan't to have it set to DEV during development. Version 2.2.1 is some kind of development version still, right? I tried to find where to download it, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Found that it will be released on Tuesday (9th)

Comment: Hopefully there's no delay. But it works though *I think*. Try to ignore it for not I guess.

Comment: This solution I poster earlier may be a solution.

[Update Glassfish 4.0 build 89 Mojarra implementation from 2.2.0 => 2.2.25][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583337/viewparam-value-not-set-in-viewscoped-bean/21089406#21089406

Comment: This solution I poster earlier may be a solution.

[Update Glassfish 4.0 build 89 Mojarra implementation from 2.2.0 => 2.2.25][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583337/viewparam-value-not-set-in-viewscoped-bean/21089406#21089406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug reported for JSF 2.2. I was dealing with the same issue awhile back.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2803

You might also want to stay away from `f:viewActions` also.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2868

Answer (score 0):

I used exactly the same configuration (Glassfish, Mojarra 2.2.0) and found out that I could circumvent the error message if I use only one child in the metadata-tag and put the listener outside of it.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.listener()}"/>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="par1" value="#{bean.val1}" />
</f:metadata>
```

The problem occurs again if you use two viewParams, see https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3080

An upgrade to the latest Mojarra Version (2.2.6 as of now) solved the problem for me.