# viewAction not working as expected

Tags: maven, jsf, viewaction

I try to run a viewAction to a request bean but I getting this message:

> The metadata component needs to be nested within a f:metadata tag. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within

I have searched the web and found out that it has been a problem down on JSF 2.2.1 (like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945943/the-metadata-component-needs-to-be-nested-within-a-fmetadata-tag-suggestion-e#20283019)), but I have set my POM to JSF 2.2.8-02.
Any ideas of what it could be and how I can solve it?

This is what I got in my facelet:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="param1" value="#{myRequestBean.param1}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{myRequestBean.action}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And myy pom.xml looks like this and I'm running on glassfish 4.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mavenproject1</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think the problem is `<scope>provided</scope>`. This signals that you **already** provided the jar to the server, and that it should'nt be included in the war.

So just delete the scopes from the jsf-dependencies and give it a try again.

You might also manually download javax.faces.jar from for example [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/) and manually replace the one in glassfish/glassfish/modules, then you don't have to remember it for all your projects. I believe javax.faces.jar replaces both jsf-api and jsf-impl.

Here are the descriptions of the various scopes from the Maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

**scope: This element refers to the classpath of the task at hand (compiling and runtime, testing, etc.) as well as how to limit the transitivity of a dependency. There are five scopes available:**

`compile` - this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

`provided` - this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it at runtime. It is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

`runtime` - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

`test` - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

`system` - this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That did really do the trick (by switching the jar)!
Just one more (simple?) question: what is the point of using the maven POM and set the version if it's just ignored and keeps running on the glassfish version?

Comment: I've updated with descriptions from the Maven documentation. I'd say you should have done as you did if you and others deployed different projects to a common server, which already had the required versions. In that case *provided* would keep your IDE happy and free of compilation errors, and your war would be the minimal size :-)